# Exporting environment variable not working from shell script

Tags: bash, scripts, powershell

I have ubuntu image in `docker`, I'm trying to setup `nodejs`, `phantomjs`, `npm` etc..

and for `PhantomJS` I need to export `QT_QPA_PLATFORM` variable and set it's value to `offscreen`.

The problem is that when I run `export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen` using `shell` script, it doesn't work, here's my `shell script`:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install nodejs -y
apt-get install phantomjs -y
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why tag powershell? If `phantomjs`needs `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen` on install I'd put the export in front.